# ListLinePlot and "irregular" Lists

Tags: plotting

I have the following List

```
SegmentFitError = {{2.72848*10^-12, 2.72848*10^-12, {3855.97, 1033.07, 4.24442, -155.604}}, {6.66273*10^-12, 8.18545*10^-12, {4692.35, 120.8, -91.0135, 15.5455}}, {7.87646*10^-13, 9.09495*10^-13, {4785.62, -50.202, 2.26041, -0.000175911}}, {0.000473295, 0.00075896, {4785.62, -50.1904, 2.25504, 0.000561967}}, {0.0560155, 0.0875888, {4786.08, -50.8692, 2.52836, -0.0313253}}, {0.0754761,  0.128737, {4786.39, -51.2871, 2.677, -0.0464049}}, {0.0870872, 0.151582, {4786.61, -51.561, 2.76422, -0.0542324}}, {0.107042, 0.195855, {4786.85, -51.8396, 2.84447, -0.0606889}}}
```

So

```
SegmentFitError[[All,3,1]] = {3855.97, 4692.35, 4785.62, 4785.62, 4786.08, 4786.39, 4786.61, 4786.85}
```

With Head of List

But

ListLinePlot[SegmentFitError[[All,3,1]]] complains with "not a list of numbers or pairs of numbers"

Any ideas why?

"12.0.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (April 6, 2019)"

Comment: no error on V 13.2.1  screen shot   ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r84bR.png)